# Eliminar un correo por una palabra clave

Tags: python

Estoy creando un analizador de correos que conecta Outlook desde Python 3.9, ademas de tomar los datos del correo analizado de la bandeja inbox extrae una palabra clave.

Con Mysql se quiere guardar los datos de los correos y poder hacer un respaldo de los que contengan la palabra clave.

Necesito ayuda para poder usar una palabra clave, en este caso **"Devops"** y que se guarde el output del correo que contenga esa palabra, si no que sea eliminado. El else se adjunta al ultimo del codigo pero no estoy segura de usar **pop()** para esto.

```
import poplib
import email
import smtplib
import mysql.connector
import re
import os
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection


#Conexion POP3 Outlook
mail = poplib.POP3_SSL('Outlook.office365.com') 
mail.user('xxx@outlook.es')
mail.pass_('*****')
# Selecciono la casilla de entrada 
new_var  = len (mail.list()[1])
print (new_var)

# Verifico los ids de los correos, que serían items
result, data = mail.uidl('search', None, "ALL")
# o Por ejemplo accedo al id más viejo
# oldest = inbox_item_list[0]
result2, email_data = mail.uidl('fetch',  '(RFC822)')
# Los datos estan en bytes, los cambio a string. Se hace con raw. Lo hago en este caso con el primer id
raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode("utf-8")
# ahora cambio este mensaje a un objeto de correo de python
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
# Ahora puedo imprimir distintos atributos del objeto, es decir del correo
print(dir(email_message))
email_message['To']
email_message['From']
email_message['Subject']
email_message['date']
email_message['message-id']
# Para acceder al contenido necesito el payload, pero este mismo esta dividido en 2 partes, puede ser una lista o texto plano
email_message.get_payload()
print(email_message.get_payload(1))
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

# Busco la palabra DevOps en el payload
x= email_message.get_payload(1)
x = email_data[0][1].decode("utf-8")
# Expresion regular para buscar
y = re.search('DevOps',x)
# y = re.findall('DevOps',x)
# Si encuentra la palabra hago lo siguiente

if y:
        print(y.group())
        # Guardo la fecha del mail en una variable
        fecha = email_message['date']
        # Guardo quien envia el correo en una variable
        de = email_message['From']
        # Guardo asunto del correo en una variable
        asunto = email_message['Subject']
        id = email_message['message-id']
        
        # Conexion a MySQL
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost", 
        user="user",  #root
        passwd="****",
        database="Data") #nombredelabase
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        # Defino el query
        sql = "INSERT INTO devops_emails (Fecha, De, Asunto) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        # Le paso el contenido de las variables
        val = (fecha, de, asunto)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

#si no encuentra la palabra cierra diractamente
else:
    y = f'No se encuentra la palabra'
print(y)
email_message.pop() #??


mail.quit()
```

Comment: y cual es el problema que en verdad tienes?, solo no estas segura de usar `pop()` o no sabes como hacer algo en específico?

Comment: claro necesito que se borre el email que no contenga la palabra clave, para esto no se si usar pop() como se muestra, o utilizar otra alternativa.

Comment: `pop()` elimina un elemento acorde a su índice, si quieres simplificarte las cosas puedes usar `remove()` que elimina el elemento de acuerdo a su contenido.

Comment: Gracias cristian! eso no comprendia.